# Mock function based on interface with jest-ts

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, azure-functions

I'm trying to find the best way to test Azure Functions written in TypeScript using Jest. This requires passing a Context object into with a log property that satisfies the following interface:

```js
   interface Logger {
        (...args: any[]): void;
        error(...args: any[]): void;
        warn(...args: any[]): void;
        info(...args: any[]): void;
        verbose(...args: any[]): void;
    }
```

I don't care about testing the calls to any of these methods, I merely care about passing a valid function into the object.  I'm looking for the quickest way to create a mock function to allow any of the methods in the interface to be called, without having to explicitly define my own Logger implementation for testing purposes.

I was hoping to get it to work with `jest-mock-extended`'s `mockDeep<T>` function but couldn't get it to work. I'd rather avoid pulling in dedicated packages like Moq.ts. Is there a simple way to create a mock function based on this interface with (ts-)jest's built-in tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you already have implemented `Logger` in your application. You can use jest's [`jest.createMockFromModule(moduleName)`](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestcreatemockfrommodulemodulename) to generate auto-mock of your implementation

[here's an example](https://replit.com/@StefanTeneff/ts-jest-4#src/Application.test.ts)

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer. This helped me realise that mocking is not what I needed and indeed I should create my own implementation stub first.

Comment: @Martijn you don't even need a stub, just use the actual implementation.